# How to disable Anti-Forgery in ASP.NET MVC (Orchard CMS)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, orchardcms

I was given a site to test and I am getting the common error when running client AJAX on different machines:

```
Exception Details: System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException: A required anti-forgery token was not supplied or was invalid.
```

Is there a way to disable this so I can run in development environments? I tried adding the attributes below to my web.config and adding a machine key, but did not do anything:

```
<pages ... enableEventValidation="false" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never" enableViewStateMac="false">...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can (temporarily) disable the token in the ASPX file(s):

```
<!-- <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %> -->
```

Comment: I don't see how this can work if your actions are still attributed with the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute. The missing token created by the line above is what the system is supposed to react to by throwing an exception.

Comment: You would (conditionally) disbale those attributes too. But I agree this probably isn't the best answer here.

Answer (score 12):

Try updating the "AntiForgery" property in module.txt:

```
AntiForgery: disabled
```

Comment: +1 Note that by default this is set to enabled if you use the orchard command line tool to create your module.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion a better way would be :

```
AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressIdentityHeuristicChecks = True;
```

Hope that helps.